# Как в тексте заменить символ перевода строки на другой?

Tags: java, android

Есть компонент TextEdit, в котором набирается текст. Набранный текст надо поместить в одну строку, а признаки перевода строки заменить на какие нибудь символы, чтобы потом восстановить этот текст, т.е. сделать его опять многострочным. 
Как это сделать?

UPD:
Ситуация такая: есть строка со значениями через разделитель ";" и в конце строки последнее значение должно быть в виде текста (который набирается отдельно см.выше). 
Таких строк (со значениями) много. И если текст (который помещен в конец строки) будет с переходами на другую строку, то это будет рушить логику работы с основными строками.

Comment: нельзя хранить в многострочном виде, а когда необходимо, пробегать по строке и убирать не нужное? По-моему заменять что-то на что-то чтобы потом опять менять обратно как-то не "рентабельно".

Comment: Дописал UPD в основном вопросе.

Comment: ну вот, перед началом "логики работы" удаляйте все переносы. Вам ведь нужно сохранить многострочность последнего значения как такового.

Comment: Дак как определить переносы? Каким символом они определяются?  И удалять их нельзя, т.к. потом надо восстановить разметку. Я конечно могу загнать текст в ArrayList и определить разные строки, но хочется понять как работать с символами переноса строки.

Comment: str.replaceAll("\n|\r\n", " "); Попробуйте так

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String in = "вадыво\n" +
        "ваыолвол\n" +
        "вадывлд";
String out = Pattern.compile("\n").matcher(in).replaceAll(" ");

Log.i("LOG_TAG", "string in - " + in);
Log.i("LOG_TAG", "string out - " + out);
```